# Implementing authentication in WildFly8

Tags: authentication, java-ee-7, wildfly

I have a working WildFly8 application and I would like to implement some kind of HTTP authentication (I am relatively new to Java EE). It can be the most basic type of authentication and it should use a database as back-end. All the tutorials I could find are ancient (from JBOSS 3 era) and probably not applicable to WildFly. Does anyone have some pointers to get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These projects should get you started in the right direction:

1. [Servlet Security](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/servlet-security)
2. [EJB Security](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-security)